Activity Refresh Issue on android 11 scanning device
I am using a scanning device (SEUIC cruise2 scanner) to get value of the barcode in my android application. In one of the activity after scanning values activity getting refreshed and it only happens in the android 11. If I am doing the same activity on different device which has android 7 it is working fine there. How to restrict the activity getting refreshed in android 11.
Is there any way activity not getting refreshed in android 11 and it should not impact the other working version.
